# How to get int to dec and dec to hex using php?

Tags: php, binary, hex, ascii, non-ascii-characters

This is hex `c4` and dec is `196`

When string length is `50` one of my project returning `\xc4`
If length is `51` then getting hex `\xc5`
length `55` = `\xc9`

length `56` = `\xca`

length `61` = `\xcf`

length `62` = `\xd0`

Continuously `\xd9` then `\xda` to continuously `\xdf` then changing `xd` to `xe` again from `\xe0` to `\xe9` and `\xea` to `\xef`

How it possible to get length `50` to hex `c4` or dec `196`?

I can convert dec to bin and bin to hex using below code:

```
$binary = decbin(50); //dec to binary
echo dechex(bindec($binary)); //binary to hex
```

Comment: `dechex(50)` always returning `32`

Comment: i want to get hex by providing length. What about `146` where you got it?

Comment: I got the 146 from your own question: you said that 50 needs to become 196. It's just basic arithmetic.

Comment: How to reverse sir?

Comment: @A__ Plz give me solution

Comment: @A__ `51` should be `c5` but returning `cc`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're possibly overthinking this: forget about the hexadecimal for a while, and note that you've already discovered that you need to convert 50 to 196. The simplest way to do that is simply to add 146. So `dechex(50 + 146)` gives you the value you need.

The rest of the sequence is, as I think you've already worked out, just hexadecimal values going upwards from there, so from what you've said, there's nothing more clever to do than add that offset to each value. Why that offset? I have no idea, because I have no idea what you're using this for.

Meanwhile, converting to binary and back isn't doing anything - it's like writing a word backwards, and then writing it back the right way again. You can just pass the number into `dechex` directly.

Comment: plz show me example, what you telling me to do

Comment: I'm not telling you to do anything very complicated - add two numbers, and then pass the result to a function. I'm not going to write the code for you, because then you'll copy and paste it and still not understand, and I'm more interested in teaching you how to think like a programmer.

Comment: your `146` technic working from `109`. Getting good result. but from `110` its returning extra `1`

Comment: `xf4` placed by `$this->text` length. Now just 99 length string supporting.

Comment: `@A__ Interesting that 50 decimal in binary is 0011 0010 - reversing each nibble one gets 1100 0100 which is hex c4. Love a good puzzle.` How?

Comment: I've answered the question you posted. I don't have access to wherever you're seeing these numbers, so can't really help beyond that. However, remember that 255 is hexadecimal FF, so the highest number you can store in one byte; if you're viewing some data one byte at a time, you'll never see a value higher than that.